# Javascript passing one function to every anchor tags

Tags: javascript, function

how to get href attribute using javascript function to every anchor tags?

```
<a href="www.facebook.com" onclick="myurl(href)"> facebook</a><br>
<a href="www.youtube.com" onclick="myurl(href)">youtube </a><br>
<a href="www.google.com" onclick="myurl(href)">google </a><br>

<script> 


function myurl(href){

 alert(href);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `this.href`.

`this` refers to the DOM element that fired the event.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="www.facebook.com" onclick="myurl(this.href)"> facebook</a><br>
<a href="www.youtube.com" onclick="myurl(this.href)">youtube </a><br>
<a href="www.google.com" onclick="myurl(this.href)">google </a><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code accordingly:

```
<a href="www.facebook.com" onclick="myurl(this)"> facebook</a><br>
<a href="www.youtube.com" onclick="myurl(this)">youtube </a><br>
<a href="www.google.com" onclick="myurl(this)">google </a><br>
<script> 
    function myurl(el){
       alert(el.href);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the object to javascript first

```
<a href="somesite.html" onclick="myurl(this)"> somebook </a>
```

Then do in your function.

```
function myurl(LinkObject) { alert(LinkObject.href); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you want to `alert` all the links. Why do you have to give `onclick="myurl(this)"` on your every anchor tag. If you have the same function for all your anchor tags. You might consider using this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].onclick = function () {
        alert(this.href);
    }
}
```